# Oracle APEX Page item Read Only option which have multiple Conditions

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I am new to Oracle apex.

I have a page with a form that is used to enter data into a table.

For Example there is `P_ID, P_NAME, P_ADD_USER, P_VERIFIED_USER, P_SECOND_ID` items. I want to make `P_SECOND_ID` read only based on multiple conditions.

Condition is

```
IF P_ADD_USER <> :APP_USER AND P_SECOND_ID = ' ' THEN 
   'P_SECOND_ID should be available to Edit.
ELSE 
    P_SECOND_ID will be read only.
```

I tried to use Type = `Item!=Value` but it is allowing me to add only one condition so is there any option that i can use both conditions and make that ITEM read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition I'd suggest in such a case is a *function that returns a Boolean* - if it returns `TRUE`, something will happen; otherwise, it won't.

So, if you want to make `P_SECOND_ID` editable if conditions you mentioned are satisfied, then you'd

```
return not (    :P_ADD_USER <> :APP_USER 
            and :P_SECOND_ID = ' '
           );
```

---

Though, did you really want to say `:P_SECOND_ID = ' '`? Is there a space character in it? Should that, perhaps, be `:P_SECOND_ID IS NULL`?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes i did use IS NULL instead of blank char. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Expression allows you to include multiple conditions. You might want to rephrase your requirement to make the item read only ( versus making it editable ) under certain conditions. If I get your requirement right, the condition to make P_SECOND_ID read only is when

:P_ADD_USER = :APP_USER OR :P_SECOND_ID is not NULL

You can use this expression directly in the SQL Expression.